# How to enable Advanced Google Services via new Cloud Projects?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-api

It seems that Google updated their projects console, and when you go to enable an advanced service in Apps Script it no longer directs you to the auto-generated project for your apps script project.

The docs say that a project will be automatically created for apps script projects.

Click Cloud Platform Project link here:

[image: advanced services enabling dialog]

Which takes you to `https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager` where it asks you to create a project.

[image: manage resources page]

There is no longer a selection or area to add APIs to the Apps Script project. If I follow that link with an existing Apps Script project that already has working advanced services, it errors out on the project Id.

How can Advanced Services be enabled on new Apps Script projects?

Comment: From the page you ended up on, click the "hamburger" icon/navigation menu, and then in the sidebar at the bottom, click "Google Cloud Platform."  Then click the same navigation icon, and from the sidebar menu, choose "APIs and Services"  That gets you to the page that should open by default.  Your account is automatically loading some other page by default.  I could only guess why.  We may never know why.  The browser and Apps Script probably need to coordinate somehow to know what URL to load, but with the new changes, it looks like something went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From the page you ended up on, click the "hamburger" icon/navigation menu, and then in the sidebar at the bottom, click "Google Cloud Platform." Then click the same navigation icon, and from the sidebar menu, choose "APIs and Services" That gets you to the page that should open by default.

Your account is automatically loading some other page by default. I could only guess why. We may never know why. The browser and Apps Script probably need to coordinate somehow to know what URL to load, but with the new changes, it looks like something went wrong.